# show tableview subtitle after selection of row

Tags: xcode, uitableview, tableview

is it possible to show the subtitle of a UITableView only if the row is selected?

So the Tableview will first show headlines, and after I have clicked on a headline, it shows me the text as subtitle?

Does anybody know how to do this?

Thank you in advance...

Dennis

Answer (score 0):

Your table's delegate will get a `-tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` message when a row is selected. It can then call the table's `-reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withAnimation:` method to reload the selected row. The data source will be asked for that cell again, and the data source can return a cell configured so that the article text is visible.